# Python integer to hex string with padding

Tags: python, hex

Consider an integer 2. I want to convert it into hex string '0x02'. By using python's built-in function `hex()`, I can get '0x2' which is not suitable for my code. Can anyone show me how to get what I want in a convenient way? Thank you.

Comment: Your description is not clear. If 2 will be 0x02, how about 20? Should it be  0x014?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
integer = 2
hex_string = '0x{:02x}'.format(integer)
```

See [pep 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/), especially *Standard Format Specifiers* for more info.

Comment: You can omit the `0x` and put a `#` in first place of the format string: `'{:#02x}'.format(integer)`. "this option adds the prefix respective '0b', '0o', or '0x' to the output value" (from https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html)

Answer (score 6):

For integers that might be very large:

```
integer = 2
hex = integer.to_bytes(((integer.bit_length() + 7) // 8),"big").hex()
```

The "big" refers to "big endian"... resulting in a string that is aligned visually as a human would expect.

You can then stick "0x" on the front if you want.

```
hex = "0x" + hex
```

Comment: minor bracketing error. Should be   hex = integer.to_bytes(((integer.bit_length() + 7) // 8),"big").hex()

Comment: Please, mention that your solution is python3 only: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_bytes'.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> integer = 2
>>> hex_string = format(integer, '#04x')  # add 2 to field width for 0x
>>> hex_string
'0x02'
```

See [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)